# How to calculate Debye length of a 2-1 electrolyte

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution

I am given the Debye length to be 10nm for 0.001M KCl at 298K. I want to know its Debye length in 0.01M CaCl2. How can this be calculated?

I know that for 1-1, the Debye length is inveresely proportional to the root of its concentration. But how can I work out for electrolytes other than 1-1?

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the derivation of the Debye length model, we would arrive at the following adapted model (doesn't assume uniform charge distribution):
$$\lambda_{D}^{2}=\frac{\kappa k_{B}T}{4\pi Z_{1}Z_{2}e^{2}c_{0}k_{c}}$$

In our equation:

- $\lambda_{D}$ is the Debye length;
- $Z_{1}$ represents the charge on the cation;
- $Z_{2}$ represents the charge on the anion;
- $\kappa$ is the dielectric constant;
- $k_{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant;
- $T$ is the absolute temperature; and
- $c_{0}$ represents the number of ions per a cubic metre of solution.

Note that the general equation assumes that $Z_{1}=Z_{2}$, hence why this is usually written as $Z^{2}$.

Keep in mind this is only applicable for calculating the Debye length for a single dissociated species in solution! Further alterations would need to be made in order to consider a mixture.

Comment: what is kappa in the numerator? isnt kappa/lambda the debye length?

Comment: Kappa represents the relative dielectric constant, $\lambda_{D}$ is the Debye length.

Comment: Another way of writing it might be $\epsilon_{r}$.

Comment: The clarification should be included in the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. While it may seem strange at first we do not use salutations in our Questions and Answers. Please use the upvote button to say thanks, or leave a comment how the post can be improved. Please also do not include edit statements in your post, the history can be usedto track changes.

Comment: how could I use the information given to work this out though? This equation doesnt make use of 10nm for KCl does it?